# How to add a list to search field dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, nssearchfield

i want to impliment a functionality like when i click on search field i need to display a list of criteria under the search field. Based on the criteria i need to search. how can i add this list to search field.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically appearing list in the `SearchField`, you have to drag and drop `outlet` of `searchfield` in your `window` first then connect the delegate of `searchfield` to `fileowners` once this is done then impelement below code:-

In this below code it contains one array of elements and after if you enter in search field any word whose length is greater than 3 then it will display the result list according to the matching words in an `array`.

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
NSArray *filterArray=@[@"item1",@"item2",@"item3",@"item4",@"test1",@"test2",@"test3",@"test4",@"test5"];
    NSString *searchString = [self.searchField stringValue];
    NSMenu *menu= [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle: @"results"];
    if (searchString.length>3)
    {
    NSArray *filteredArray = [filterArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like  %@", [searchString stringByAppendingString:@"*"]]];
    for (NSString *addMenuItem in filteredArray)
    {
    [menu addItemWithTitle: addMenuItem action: @selector(someAction:) keyEquivalent: @""];
    }

    NSEvent *event = [NSEvent otherEventWithType: NSApplicationDefined
                                        location: [self.searchField frame].origin
                                   modifierFlags: 0
                                       timestamp: 0
                                    windowNumber: [[self.searchField window] windowNumber]
                                         context: [[self.searchField window] graphicsContext]
                                         subtype: NSAppKitDefined
                                           data1: 0
                                           data2: 0];
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu: [menu autorelease] withEvent: event forView: self.searchField];
}
}
-(void)someAction:(id)sender
{
    //if you want to perform some action write here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is like, if supoose there are three arrays are there. i want to display the 3 array names below the search field as a list.. if i will select any one of them then the search should happen in that perticular selected array. i need how to display that array list?

Comment: Ohk this is also possible. But one thing is there then why you are taking searchfield here. Because in searchfield user can type the words and then on the basis of that it will search??

Comment: I just nee to search in that perticular field(array) only, which user can select. Now global search is happening in my code. Instead of giving all the results,i need to give options to the user in which field they want to search.

Comment: Ok so you mean to say if user clicks on the searchfield then it should display the list of 3 array names and then if click on any then it should display the list accordingly?? right??

Comment: Ok suneetha, As of now i am not having mac with me. So sorry for that i cannot provide you the solution code. But i will tell you the logic. After searchfield take two button one is list button and search button and write the action on that inside that copy the above delegate code but change the array list to your list. So that when user click on list button it will display the list and then when user select any name inside the list. Append that particular name in that searchfield. Now, on the basis of that search the name and display the list accordingly. Let me know if you have any issue>